# Deep link to open Safari from another app

Tags: ios, safari, deep-linking

Is there a deep link that will open a page in Safari from another app?

I have tried

```
safari://https://www.google.com

safari://www.google.com
```

but it doesn't work. I get the pop-up asking if I want to leave the current app, but Safari doesn't open.

This is the equivalent for Chrome, which works:

```
googlechrome://www.google.com
```

Comment: Have you tried just `https://www.google.com`?

Comment: That's just going to open that page in the current app browser. I need to open Safari.

Comment: Are you doing this from a web app or a native app? If you are using a web view in a native app, which component are you using?

Comment: This would be from the website. If someone views a certain page in the Facebook/Messenger browser then I'd want them to have the option of opening a page in Safari. From what I'm seeing, there doesn't seem to be a deep link URL for Safari like for Chrome and many other apps.

Comment: @user984003 did you find any solution? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: No, I never did.

Answer (score -2):

```
safari-https://www.google.com ...
```

is the simple solution to this issue

Comment: Doesn't work. Received `Failed to open URL safari-https://google.com: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10814 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSLine=225, _LSFunction=-[_LSDOpenClient openURL:options:completionHandler:]}`